# How To Show Store Name On The Product Thumbnail In Dokan Multivendor Plugin by weDevs

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, dokan

I'm using Dokan Multivendor Plugin by weDevs and have an issue with some custom code..

Here is the code which helps you [to display Vendor Name](https://nayemdevs.com/display-vendor-name/) On The Product Thumbnail In Dokan:

```
    //woocommerce
/*
Show Seller name on the product thumbnail
For WooCommerce 

*/

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title','sold_by' );
function sold_by(){
?>
    </a>
    <?php
        global $product;
        $author     = get_user_by( 'id', $product->post->post_author );
        $store_info = dokan_get_store_info( $author->ID );
        if ( !empty( $store_info['store_name'] ) ) { ?>
                <span class="details">
                    <?php printf( 'Sold by: <a href="%s">%s</a>', dokan_get_store_url( $author->ID ), $author->display_name ); ?>
                </span>
        <?php 
    } 

}
```

But I need **to display Store Name** instead of Vendor Name On The Product Thumbnail..

Trying to change this string to achieve this goal:

```
<?php printf( 'Sold by: <a href="%s">%s</a>', dokan_get_store_url( $author->ID ), $author->display_name ); ?>
```

To this one:

```
<?php printf( 'Sold by: <a href="%s">%s</a>', dokan_get_store_url( $author->ID ), $author->store_name ); ?>
```

but it doesn't work..

Answer (score 3):

Try this , I am assuming you are using WooCommerce V3.0+

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title','sold_by' );
    function sold_by(){
    ?>
        </a>
        <?php
            global $product;
            $seller = get_post_field( 'post_author', $product->get_id());
 $author     = get_user_by( 'id', $seller );

            $store_info = dokan_get_store_info( $author->ID );
            if ( !empty( $store_info['store_name'] ) ) { ?>
                    <span class="details">
                        <?php printf( 'Sold by: <a href="%s">%s</a>', dokan_get_store_url( $author->ID ), $author->display_name ); ?>
                    </span>
            <?php 
        } 

    }
```

Comment: Hi! @rafsuntaskin! Thanks for your answer!
Unfortunately your code returns the same result as my one.

Nevertheless I've found the code I need. All I've changed was this string and I got what I need: 

<?php printf( 'Sold by: <a href="%s">%s</a>', dokan_get_store_url( $author->ID ), $store_info['store_name'] ); ?>