# Add a popup button in WooCommerce shop page to show dokan seller info and rate for each product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming, dokan

I'm facing a problem for making a facility in WooCommerce shop page. I'm using Dokan plugin and we have some vendors. I want to create a pop-up button on each cart of product and when a user click on it a pop-up shows some info from the seller of this product including rates and name, please help me if you can. The pop-up button could be the seller avatar.

We tried some different answers code, but all of them shows data only for the first product in the list.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title','sold_by' );
    function sold_by(){
    ?>
        </a>
        <?php
            global $product;
            $seller = get_post_field( 'post_author', $product->get_id());
            $author  = get_user_by( 'id', $seller );
            $vendor = dokan()->vendor->get( $seller );

            $store_info = dokan_get_store_info( $author->ID );
            if ( !empty( $store_info['store_name'] ) ) { ?>
                    <span class="details">
                        <?php printf( 'sold by: <a href="%s">%s</a>', $vendor->get_shop_url(),  $vendor->get_shop_name() ); ?>
                    </span>
            <?php 
        } 

    }
```

Reference:

[How To Show Store Name On The Product Thumbnail In Dokan Multivendor Plugin by weDevs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43632297/how-to-show-store-name-on-the-product-thumbnail-in-dokan-multivendor-plugin-by-w/43653720#43653720)

Comment: What does mean *"on each cart of product"*? Your question is very unclear, not detailed and poorly understandable. Please edit your question.